# Flex iframe set priority?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

How to set priority(like send to back) for iframe?

Comment: has this question got anything to do with Flex at all?

Comment: In flex, iframe always shows in top, it's overlaps other component.in flash we need to set some priority like (bring to front,send to back,bring to froware) so only i search any facility to available in flex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suffring this problem recently, it costs me a lot of time and I find no solution about this.

this article lists some disadvantages about iframe in flex
http://www.deitte.com/archives/2008/07/dont_use_iframe.htm

another way to embed rich text, i think, is to use TextFLow, in RichText, you could easily find good examples in API

however, iframe is still useful, when developer actually want it on top. Using it with TitleWindow is a good idea. (correct me if i'm wrong)

If anyone have a better idea, please hit me, I will greatly appreciate